# Cannot unpack a zip object multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is this not working?:

```
t = zip([3],[4],[3])
print("1:",*t)
print("2:",*t)
```

We cannot unpack a second time in Python, why is that?

Comment: How is it not working? What happens when you try it?

Comment: If you dont know why its not obvious

Comment: What is missing is a decent problem description. *This is not working* doesn't tell us anything about what you were expecting and what happened instead. Sure, the experts can take a good guess, but that's not helpful for other future visitors with the same issue, they won't find this question.

Comment: @TimCastelijns: I realised, and edited the comment already. :-)

Answer (score 12):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) returns an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html) in Python 3.x instead of a list like it did in Python 2.x.  This means that, after you unpack it once, it will become exhausted and no longer usable:

```
>>> t = zip([3],[4],[3])
>>> print("1:",*t)
1: (3, 4, 3)
>>> list(t) # t is now empty
[]
>>>
```

You need to explicitly convert the iterator into a [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html) (a list, tuple, etc). if you want to unpack it multiple times:

```
>>> t = tuple(zip([3],[4],[3]))
>>> print("1:",*t)
1: (3, 4, 3)
>>> print("2:",*t)
2: (3, 4, 3)
>>>
```